# Tables and Data being in all connections instead the one that I made them in,when I make new connections I have to drop tables with same names

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Just asking is there any way that I can set so my tables and data don't "flow over" from one connection to another,instead they stay in the connecting in which I made them

Comment: Tables belong to user who created them. I can't imagine what might be wrong in your case; could you, please, post a screenshot which shows what you are saying?

Comment: Take a look at temporary tables